# Solving Laplace's equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, boundary-value-problem

I've been looking at solving this equation with u(x,0)=u(x,1)=u(0,y)=0 and u(1,y)=sin(pi*y) where (x,y)∈(0,1)x(0,1)

I have solved by hand for h=1/2 and h=1/3 (using the 5-point stencil) however I am struggling with the coding

This is for h=1/3

> ```
> clear; clc % Clear workspace/command window
> % Inputs
> Nx = 3;
> Ny = 3;
> Lx = 1;
> Ly = 1;
> % Grid
> x = linspace (0, Lx, Nx); % Mesh
> y = linspace (0, Ly, Ny);
> dx = x(2)-x(1); % Mesh size
> dy = y(2)-y(1);
>
> % Initialise Matrices
>
> N = 4; % Number of unknowns
> A=zeros(N,N); % N rows, N columns
> b=zeros(N,1); % N rows, 1 column
>
> % Interior points (not on boundary)
>
> for i=2:Nx-1 % Loop over x direction, first and last grid points skipped
>     for j=2:Ny-1 % Loop over y direction, first and last grid points skipped
>         n=i+(j-1)*Nx; % Convert i,j grid point to the nth grid point
>         A(n,n)=-4; % Main diagonal
>         A(n,n-1)=1; % Off diagonal to left
>         A(n,n+1)=1; % Off diagonal to right
>         A(n,n-Nx)=1; % Far off diagonal to left
>         A(n,n+Nx)=1; % Far off diagonal to right
>         b(n,1)=0; % Source term
>     end
> end
>
> % Boundary conditions
>
> % Left boundary condition u = 0
>
> i=1;
> for j=1:Ny
>     n=i+(j-1)*Nx; % nth row for this ij
>     A(n,n)=1; % Main diagonal
>     b(n,1)=0; % Boundary condition at y_j
> end
>
> % Right boundary condition u = sin(pi*y)
>
> i=N;
> for j=1:Ny
>     n=i+(j-1)*Nx; % nth row for this ij
>     A(n,n)=1; % Main diagonal
>     b(n,1)=sin(pi*y(j)); % Boundary condition at y_j
> end
>
> % Bottom boundary condition u = 0
>
> j=1;
> for i=1:Nx
>     n=i+(j-1)*Ny; % nth row for this ij
>     A(n,n)=1; % Main diagonal
>     b(n,1)=0; % Boundary condition at x_i
> end
>
> % Top boundary condition u = 0
>
> j=1;
> for i=1:Nx
>     n=i+(j-1)*Ny; % nth row for this ij
>     A(n,n)=1; % Main diagonal
>     b(n,1)=0; % Boundary condition at x_i
> end
>
> % Solving A*u=b
> % u = inv(A)*b 
> u_vec = A\b;
>
> Convert vector solution to a 2D array
>
>  for i=1:Nx
>      for j=1:Ny
>          n=i+(j-1)*Nx; % nth row for this ij
>          u(i,j) = u_vec(n)
>      end
>  end
>
>  % Plot result
>  
> surf(x,y,u') % ' takes transpose
> xlabel('x')
> ylabel('y')
> ```

with results of:

u =

NaN

u =

NaN   NaN

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN     0     0

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN     0

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN     0     0

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN     0

u =

NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN

any help would be great

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.  If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: @Mol Could you be more specific about where you're having trouble? Does your code work properly for h = 1/3? What goes wrong when you try to use this code in general?

Comment: @Ben Grossman You are right. Thanks

Comment: See https://www.slideshare.net/ayaozaki91/fdm-numerical-solution-of-laplace-equation-using-matlab

Comment: I will edit my question to show my results, thank you Jean also. My code does not work for any h, I believe my A might be too large for the problem

Comment: what is h defined as?